# Mysql return more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have this query.

```
SELECT notes.id,enter.name as 'enter_name',step.title as 'flow status',notes.user_name as user_created,notes.created,notes.rel_client_id,td_doc_nr.value_string as 'document number',enter.enter_code,
    IF(!ISNULL(td_doc_nr.value_string),
     (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ',') from notes d 
        join note_bundles b on b.note_id = d.id
        join note_products p on p.doc_bundle_id = b.id
        join note_product_get_fields f on f.doc_product_id = p.id
        join note_product_get_field_data fd on fd.get_field_id = f.id
        where d.doc_nr = td_doc_nr.value_string
        and value_string ='auto')
,NULL) as test
FROM notes notes
JOIN notes_steps step ON  step.id  = notes.step_id 
JOIN notes_enters enter ON enter.id = notes.enter_id
    LEFT JOIN notes_custom_fields tf_doc_nr ON tf_doc_nr.name = 'note_number' AND tf_doc_nr.rel_entity_id = enter.id
    LEFT JOIN notes_custom_field_data td_doc_nr ON td_doc_nr.rel_entity_id = notes.id AND
 td_doc_nr.field_instance_id = tf_doc_nr.id 
WHERE notes.enter_id in  (777) AND notes.status = 1
```

I added this subquery to the 'if statement'

```
 SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ',') from nontes d 
    join note_bundles b on b.note_id = d.id
    join note_products p on p.doc_bundle_id = b.id
    join note_product_get_fields f on f.doc_product_id = p.id
    join note_product_get_field_data fd on fd.get_field_id = f.id
    where d.doc_nr = 'G7777777'
    and value_string ='auto'
```

After this I added a new column.

```
 SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ','),GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.msisdn SEPARATOR ',') from notes d 
    join note_bundles b on b.note_id = d.id
    join note_products p on p.doc_bundle_id = b.id
    join note_product_get_fields f on f.doc_product_id = p.id
    join note_product_get_field_data fd on fd.get_field_id = f.id
    where d.doc_nr = 'G7777777'
    and value_string ='auto'
```

It returns two columns.
How can I return two columns?Is it possible? :) Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Please could you give example input data, and what you want the output data to be?

Comment: So you want to return two columns and you return two columns. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to return more than one field with a subquery.  If you want the quick fix just copy the query twice.

Comment: @afuzzyllama I thought about it..thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subquery inside an IF statement can't return multiple columns. You will need to join the subquery into the results, and pull out the two separate columns individually:

```
SELECT ...
    IF(!ISNULL(td_doc_nr.value_string), sub.one, NULL) as one,
    IF(!ISNULL(td_doc_nr.value_string), sub.two, NULL) as two
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  d.doc_nr, GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ','),GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.msisdn SEPARATOR ',') from documents d 
    join document_bundles b on b.document_id = d.id
    join document_products p on p.doc_bundle_id = b.id
    join document_product_cstm_fields f on f.doc_product_id = p.id
    join document_product_cstm_field_data fd on fd.cstm_field_id = f.id
    where value_string ='auto'
    group by d.doc_nr
) sub on sub.doc_nr = td_doc_nr.value_string
```

Answer (score 2):

A correlated subquery inside an IF statement can only return 1 column and 1 row, this is why you are getting the error. However, looking over your query the only outer reference inside the subquery is

```
d.doc_nr = td_doc_nr.value_string
```

So you do not need actually need a correlated subquery and you can achieve the same result by moving the subquery to a join and grouping by doc_nr within the subquery, which will probably be much more efficient, and it will allow you to return the 2 columns you want:

```
SELECT  tickets.id,
        source.name as 'source_name',
        flow_stage.title as 'flow status',
        tickets.user_name as user_created,
        tickets.created,
        tickets.rel_client_id,
        td_doc_nr.value_string as 'document number',
        source.source_code,
        IF(!ISNULL(td_doc_nr.value_string), ProductNames, NULL) as test,
        d.MSISDNS
FROM    tickets tickets
        JOIN tickets_flow_stages flow_stage 
            ON flow_stage.id  = tickets.flow_stage_id 
        JOIN tickets_sources source 
            ON source.id = tickets.source_id
        LEFT JOIN tickets_custom_fields tf_doc_nr 
            ON tf_doc_nr.name = 'document_number' 
            AND tf_doc_nr.rel_entity_id = source.id
        LEFT JOIN tickets_custom_field_data td_doc_nr 
            ON td_doc_nr.rel_entity_id = tickets.id 
            AND td_doc_nr.field_instance_id = tf_doc_nr.id 
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  d.Doc_nr,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ',') AS ProductNames,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.msisdn SEPARATOR ',') AS MSISDNS
            from    documents d 
                    INNER JOIN document_bundles b 
                        ON b.document_id = d.id
                    INNER JOIN document_products p 
                        ON p.doc_bundle_id = b.id
                    INNER JOIN document_product_cstm_fields f 
                        ON f.doc_product_id = p.id
                    INNER JOIN document_product_cstm_field_data fd 
                        ON fd.cstm_field_id = f.id
            WHERE   value_string ='auto'
            GROUP BY d.Doc_nr
        ) d
            ON d.doc_nr = td_doc_nr.value_string
WHERE   tickets.source_id IN (114,122,125,129,131) 
AND     tickets.status = 1
```