# How to return the table using mysql Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL. I want to return the table using MySQL  function. In SQL its working fine but not in MySQL.    I attach my partial code

```
 DELIMITER $$

    CREATE FUNCTION myFunction() RETURNS @tmptable TABLE (item varchar(20))
    BEGIN  

        insert  into @tmptable(item) values('raja')     


        return
     END; $$
```

Comment: In MySQL, a function cannot return a table. You would have to use a stored procedure for that.

Comment: What do you mean with "*In SQL it's working fine?*". You **are** using SQL....

Answer (score 9):

Using functions you can not return a table.

However you can use stored procedure to return the table.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_Name`(OUT po_ErrMessage   VARCHAR(200))
 BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
SET po_ErrMessage = 'Error in procedure sp_Name';
 END;

 SELECT * FROM table_name;
END
```

Comment: Ya its working fine in procedure. Is there any way to return more than one row  using MySQL function. If Possible means give example

Comment: You can check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850731/mysql-return-more-than-one-row It will definitely help!!!