# Working on a mysql database. But i need help on creating a function

Tags: mysql

This the results i need to recreate from a function.

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| exhibition_name | start_date | end_date   | Paintings |
+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| E1              | 12-18-2015 | 12-18-2015 |         7 |
| E2              | 11-10-2015 | 11-13-2015 |         2 |
| Scupture show   | 10-20-2015 | 10-25-2015 |         4 |
+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

These tables below are what i am using and values I have already inserted values into them

```
CREATE TABLE Exhibition(
name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
start_date VARCHAR(11),
end_date VARCHAR(11),
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE Shown_at(
art INT NOT NULL,
exhibition_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (art, exhibition_name),
FOREIGN KEY (art) REFERENCES Art_object(id_no), 
FOREIGN KEY (exhibition_name) REFERENCES Exhibition(name)
);
```

This is my attempt to complete the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION No_of_painting_exhibited(exhb_name VARCHAR(15), startd VARCHAR(11), enddVARCHAR(11), num_paint INT)

RETURNS VARCHAR(15), VARCHAR(11), VARCHAR(11), INT
DETERMINISTIC
SELECT exhibition_name, start_date, end_date, COUNT(*) as Paintings
FROM Shown_at, Exhibition
WHERE name = exhibition_name
Group by exhibition_name;
END
```

Comment: Hi Angel, Please provide the specific issue what you are facing in your attempt, that way your question will get better attention in SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues

- You need to change to a [Procedure, not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251672/how-to-return-the-table-using-mysql-function) in order to return a table
- Number of paintings is an output, so you can remove the `num_paint` parameter
- Since Exhibition name is a primary key, this isn't desirable as an input if you intend showing a grouped list of many exhibitions
- Seemingly you would want to use the start and end date as parameters
- You should use strong date types for dates, not VARCHAR
- Please use ANSI JOINS to join tables, rather than joining on the where clause
- You might consider using a surrogate key (e.g. another id, guid, etc) for Exhibition - names can be a problematic choice.

How about (with `DELIMITER` other than `;`, e.g. `//`):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE No_of_painting_exhibited(
  startd DATE, 
  endd DATE)
BEGIN
    SELECT exhibition_name, start_date, end_date, COUNT(*) as Paintings
    FROM Exhibition
       INNER JOIN Shown_at
       ON name = exhibition_name
    WHERE end_date >= startd and start_date <= endd
    GROUP BY exhibition_name, start_date, end_date;
END;
```

Executed like so:

```
CALL No_of_painting_exhibited('2015/11/01','2016/01/01');
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3796a/1)

Comment: might want to talk about delimiters because that and the fiddle won't work for a neebie

Comment: @StuartLC THank you, i tried the example in fiddle. But i just had a question in the call feature you put '2016/01/01' as the second input. Why did you put that date, because when you populated the table that date never came up?

Comment: Because I've used DATE data types, we can use comparisons such as <, >= and between, so we have options other than an exact match.