# User-Defined Functions Returning Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

PostgreSQL allows you to define a function that returns a table. Does MySQL provide a similar feature? My research suggests not, but I'd be grateful if someone could show me otherwise.

Essentially, I want to add a "running-total" column to a rowset, and this is one of the options I'm investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return a table using MySQL function, but you can using a stored procedure, I got something like this:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_Name`(OUT po_ErrMessage   VARCHAR(200))
 BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
SET po_ErrMessage = 'Error in procedure sp_Name';
 END;

 SELECT * FROM table_name;
END
```

And for more information please [refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251672/how-to-return-the-table-using-mysql-function)

Comment: That 's what I thought. It's not the answer I was hoping for, but it is what I expected, with a little sample code thrown in as a bonus.