# how to get simply output natural numbers using function?

Tags: sql-server

Input number is: (1,10)

Output number is:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: You tagged your question with sql-server and mysql which are very different RDBMS

Comment: its possible to get the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged `MySQL` & `SQL-Serevr` !

The answer is almost for `SQL Server`.

**FOR SQL-Server:-**

Maybe there are another approaches for achieving this.

My approach is via using [Table-Valued User-Defined Functions.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx)

**Demo:-**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetRanges(@start int, @end int)
RETURNS @MyTable TABLE 
(
    Numbers int
)
AS 
-- Returns the first name, last name, job title, and contact type for the specified contact.
BEGIN
    WHILE (@start <=@end)
    BEGIN
        insert into  @MyTable values (@start)
        SET @start = @start + 1
    END
    RETURN;
End
GO
```

Now execute the function as next:-

```
Select * from dbo.GetRanges(1,10)
```

**Result:-**

[image]

**FOR MySQL:-**

Using functions you can not return a table, here a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251672/how-to-return-the-table-using-mysql-function), hopes help.

---

Another approach without using `While`.

Via using `ROW_NUMBER()` as next:-

```
SELECT numbers From
(
    select ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY so1.id) as numbers from sysobjects so1,sysobjects 
) a

where numbers between 1 and 10
```

Comment: This will be **super slow** compared with various other approaches doing this *ad-hoc*... *Multi-Statement-Functions* are something evil already. In combination with a `WHILE` it is really, really bad...

Comment: plz have a look to another approach, and give me your opinion, thx,

Comment: An improvement was to use `TOP` like here: `select TOP(@EndNumber) ROW_NUMBER() ...` Your approach has to get the list first, just to filter it down again... And you are bound to a filled sys.objects table (rather short in test dbs very often... Better from this point of view is `master..spt_values`

Comment: I was thinking about `Top` and it will be good just if minNumber is 1, I wish to set the query as generic one , thanks for ur all comments.

Comment: No problem acutally, look at my answer... I use some calculation for `TOP`, the offset and an intervall...

Answer (score 1):

Try this for SQL Server

```
CREATE FUNCTION fuGetNumbers
(   
    @StartNumber INT NULL,
    @EndNumber INT NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH nums AS (
                SELECT @StartNumber AS value UNION ALL SELECT value + 1 AS value FROM nums WHERE nums.value < @EndNumber
             )
    SELECT * FROM nums

)
```

and you can call it

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fuGetNumbers(1,10) OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: From 1 to 10 it will be okay, but a recursive approach is a hidden RBAR. This will be not so fast with larger sets...

Answer (score 1):

This will return up to 10^9 running numbers out of nowhere and lightning fast

```
DECLARE @start INT = 1;
DECLARE @end INT = 10;
DECLARE @intervall INT=1;


WITH x AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(N))--10^1
,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS N2 CROSS JOIN x N3) --10^3
,Tally AS(SELECT TOP(@end-@start +1) (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)))*@intervall + @start -1  AS Nr FROM N3 
          CROSS JOIN N3 N6 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N9)
SELECT *
FROM Tally
```

### UPDATE

Same as **inline-table-valued-function**, very easy to join into each select

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RunningNumbers
(
 @start INT
,@end INT
,@intervall INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

WITH x AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(N))--10^1
,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS N2 CROSS JOIN x N3) --10^3
,Tally AS(SELECT TOP(@end-@start +1) (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)))*@intervall + @start -1  AS Nr FROM N3 
          CROSS JOIN N3 N6 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N9)
SELECT *
FROM Tally
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.RunningNumbers(1,10,1)
```

Comment: Voting up, this answer is better than mine  while using `inline-table-valued-function` as performance aspect.