# Mysql 'split ' and 'replace' functions/procedures

Tags: mysql, sql

maybe a stupid question, but as far as I understood MySQL's functions cannot return a table as described here: [How to return the table using mysql Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251672/how-to-return-the-table-using-mysql-function)

So my question is how to create a function that splits a string with a delimiter (let's say space ' ' ) and after that replaces some chars in every single token created? If that is not possible and instead a procedure is needed, can a procedure be called as a function?

Let's try to explain what I need to do:

Starting from a String "MANGA 23" I need to apply a transformation to the first token (MANGA) and another to the second one (23) for example:

```
"MANGA 23" --> "MAN 43"

SPLIT (MANGA, ' '); -- split the string 'MANGA' using the delimiter space
REPLACE ('GA','',token1); -- replace from token1 'GA' with empty string
REPLACE ('2','4',token2); -- replace from token2 '2' with '4'
```

I need to use the replace function to a specific token, because the replace cannot be applied to the whole string, because it can change the final result in some cases.

Is there a way (using MySQL) to create this functions/procedures and use them in a SQL statement, like  ?

```
select * from mytable where TRANSFORM(column1)='MAN 34'
```

(where 'TRASFORM' is a function that uses the logic defined above)

or there is no way and it's better to move that logic from DB to the application?

Comment: A stored function should be able to do this. It doesn't need to return a table, it's just returning a single string. You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to extract a token from a string.

Comment: You can also use looping statements in the function if you want to operate on all the tokens in the string.

Comment: Thank you Barmar for your suggestions, I will try to understand how to accomplish this in MySQL then. I suppose the performance should be better than do it at application level.